# how to make linechart using Graphview library

Tags: android, json, graphics, linechart, android-graphview

i want to make a linechart using Graphview library that i taken from http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html my problem is i want to take data from JSON as bellow :

```
[
{
    "lji_invest": "Excellink Aggressive Fund",
    "persen_hke1": 0,
    "lnu_nilai": 3611.468,
    "lji_id": "03",
    "tanggal": "01/04/2013"
},
{
    "lji_invest": "Excellink Aggressive Fund",
    "persen_hke1": 0.001143302391160603,
    "persen_hmin1": 0.001143302391160603,
    "lnu_nilai": 3615.597,
    "selisih": 4.129,
    "lji_id": "03",
    "tanggal": "02/04/2013"
},
{
    "lji_invest": "Excellink Aggressive Fund",
    "persen_hke1": 0.005411926673585367,
    "persen_hmin1": 0.004263749527394784,
    "lnu_nilai": 3631.013,
    "selisih": 15.416,
    "lji_id": "03",
    "tanggal": "03/04/2013"
}]
```

i want to display "lnu_nilai" and "tanggal" in linechart, i have tried, but i got nothing. this is my source code :

```
public class LineChartAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute (){
        super.onPreExecute();
        Dialog=new ProgressDialog(LineChart.this);
        Dialog.setMessage("Mohon Tunggu Sebentar...");
        Dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        Dialog.setCancelable(true);
        Dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String url= "http://www.sinarmaslife.co.id/E-Policy/ios/NabChart.htm?id=03&nilai=7";
        try {
            JSONParser jp= new JSONParser();
            JSONArray ja= jp.takeJson(url);

            for (int i=0; i<ja.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                if (jo.has("lnu_nilai")) 
                    map.put("lnu_nilai", jo.get("lnu_nilai").toString());

                if (jo.has("tanggal")) 
                    map.put("tanggal", jo.get("tanggal").toString());
                NabList.add(map);
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        Dialog.dismiss();
        GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries(new GraphViewData[NabList.size()] );
        {
            for (int i=0; i<NabList.size();i++){

                HashMap MapA= new HashMap();
                MapA=(HashMap) NabList.get(i);

            }
        }
        GraphView graphView;

    graphView = new LineGraphView(
            this // context
                    , "GraphViewDemo" // heading
            );

        graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1);
        layout.addView(graphView);

        };  
    }
}
```

my application got force close, and the chart didn't display....  i don't know where is my fault, i hope somebody can help me to solve this problem, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In android development there is tool which is called LogCat you can check reason why your app is being forced closed in that.